# Autofocus of Draftjs test editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

How can I ensure that the sole `draft-js` textbox on my UI autofocuses on page load?

There is a documented method called [`focus`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor.html#methods), however I am unsure of the syntax required for implementation.

Answer (score 9):

If your editor is initiated with some default value then doing just `this.refs.editor.focus()` will have cursor at starting of the text. So to move cursor to the end we need to do something like this in `componentDidMount`

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      editorState:  EditorState.moveFocusToEnd(this.state.editorState), // EditorState imported from draft-js
    });
  }
```

https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/blob/master/draft-js-plugins-editor/src/Editor/moveSelectionToEnd.js -- link to the method

Comment: underrated answer

Answer (score 6):

see [here](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-managing-focus.html#content)

basically, you'd do something like

```
<Editor ref="someRef" />
```

and

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.refs.someRef.focus();
}
```

Comment: I did wonder if the answer would involve the component lifecycle, which I hadn't needed to look at until now. will investigate :)

Comment: I can confirm this works with the new react useEffect hook. Although I used my ref like so: `ref={someRef}`, and in my UseEffect, I have `someRef.current.focus();` with an empty array passed in as a dependency.